# Mongo query always returns the value exists in database, when it does not

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query for a name field in mongodb and with the following code I always get the response that the value is a duplicate.

```
var checkUserName =  function (userName, email, res){
    User.findOne({ name : userName }, function () {
        if(userName  && typeof userName !== 'undefined'){
            res.send("duplicate");
        }else{
            checkEmail(email);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm newbie in mongo but i think if(userName && typeof userName !== 'undefined') always will give you true.. and as far as i know.. findOne will just bring you back 1 result even if you have more than one... so maybe mongo have some method to this or bring all and use lenght property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are currently ignoring the answer from the database completely and are just checking your input again. This cannot work. Mongoose returns the answer of the query as the second parameter of the callback function (the first is always there to signal errors) - try something like this:

```
var checkUserName =  function (userName, email, res){

  User.findOne({ name : userName }, function (err, userFromDb) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("there was an error: " + err;
        return res.send("err: " + err.message);
    }
    if(userFromDb) {
        res.send("duplicate");
    } else {
        checkEmail(email);
    }
  });
}
```